# Importing a bunch of files in matlab

Tags: matlab, date, time

I am trying to extract date and time from the files in my matlab code so i can plot them with time as x-axis.
i have 1000s of files created in seconds.
using

```
filetime=dir('C:\New\1_23_55 PM.txt');
timestamp=filetime.date
```

i do get the time. But the problem is when i use loop to read all files as soon as i assign a variable for file name in the command this time attrib does not work.

Any help how to extract time from the file creation would help

Thanks

my code for the loop

```
dirData   = dir('*.txt') ; %# Match file names with a wildcard 
dataFiles = {dirData.name}; 
nFiles    = numel(dataFiles)             %# Number of files 

for iFile = 1:nFiles                 
    data         = dlmread(dataFiles{iFile});
    running_file = iFile;
    p            = dataFiles{iFile};
    % ...
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your loop?

Comment: Yuo can use `s = dir('C:\New\*.txt')` to query them all at once;

Comment: Not really this query only gives the timestamp of the first txt file

Comment: @macduff  : i have posted my code for loop. I am trying to save the time/date obtained from the file name ( its creation time) and save as a column

Comment: Are you saying that your results are overwritten?

Comment: @OlegKomarov : I tried the above code in run window and thus i guess it got over written. sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
for iFile = 1:nFiles
    timestamp = dirData(iFile).date;

    % ...
end
```

Comment: I think his problem is he has a column of dates and a column of data, and he ends up overwriting the whole stuff at each iteration.

Comment: @Ahmed :Thanks that was easy just had to rewrite in  matrix with datenum to store them.